# Compare two doubles to N decimal places

Tags: c++, floating-point

I have a function that compares two doubles to N decimal places.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class RelType : int { Less, Equal, Greater };

RelType _compare(double v1, double v2, int multiplier)
{
    if (std::round(v1 * multiplier) == std::round(v2 * multiplier))
        return RelType::Equal;
    if (v1 < v2)
        return RelType::Less;
    return RelType::Greater;
}

template<int N> RelType compare(double, double) { static_assert(false, "Not implemented."); }
template<> RelType compare<5>(double v1, double v2) { return _compare(v1, v2, 100000); }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double v1 = 1.0;                        // 1.0000000000000000
    double v2 = (1.0 / 13.67) * 13.67;      // 0.99999999999999989

    cout << std::boolalpha;
    cout << (v1 == v2) << endl;                               // false (not what we expected)
    cout << (compare<5>(v1, v2)==RelType::Equal) << endl;     // true (correct behaviour)
    cout << (v1 > v2) << endl;                                // true (not what we expected)
    cout << (compare<5>(v1, v2)==RelType::Greater) << endl;   // false (correct behaviour)

    return 0;
}
```

My main two questions are about the efficiency and correctness of the `_compare` helper function. Are there any pitfalls to consider that might not be obvious at first glance?

Comment: What's the purpose of the 5 in `compare<5>()`? I don't get it...

Comment: The template parameter denotes the number of decimal places to be compared.

Comment: The `N` parameter defines what the `multiplier` argument to `_compare` will be: `multiplier` = 10 to the power of `N`

Comment: Okay, I see that now, but the value `100000` is hardcoded, so the template parameter serves not actual purpose. You could very well remove those templates and rename a single function to `compare_5_decimal_places()` or similar. The template functions are certainly unclear.

Comment: It is important to note that this `compare` function specifically compares rounded values. Please see Ian's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem I have with your code is with these templates:

> ```
> template<int N> RelType compare(double, double) { static_assert(false, "Not implemented."); }
> template<> RelType compare<5>(double v1, double v2) { return _compare(v1, v2, 100000); }
> ```

They are misleading. The `5` in the second function should be supposed to denote the number of decimal places to be compared, however, it is not implemented to do so, being only used as name decoration. E.g.:

```
// Comparing 5 decimal places:
cout << (compare<5>(v1, v2) == RelType::Equal) << endl;

// Also comparing 5 decimal places:
// (In actuality, a shady compile error due 
// to the static_assert. But we can do better...)
cout << (compare<8>(v1, v2) == RelType::Equal) << endl;
```

I see no point in having a parameter if it always has to have the same value, so one improvement to the interface would be just getting rid of the templates and having a single function that *always* compares with 5 decimal places and no other option.

Another possibility, if you need to have the ability to configure the number of decimal palaces at compile time, would be actually using the `N` parameter to compute the multiplier, instead of hardcoding a value. You can do so with a [compile-time power function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16443682/1198654):

```
template<int N> RelType compare(double v1, double v1)
{
    constexpr auto multiplier = compile_time_pow(10, N);
    // ... the rest ...
}
```

Note that in the above link C++11 is utilized, though it is probably possible to achieve the same without `constexpr`.

Comment: Thank you. `compile_time_pow` is what I am looking for. Awesome!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a generalized function suggested by @glampert

```
constexpr auto multiplier = compile_time_pow(10, N);
```

You can also use a simplified version that assumes the number 10.

```
template <int N> struct Multiplier
{
   static const int value = 10 * Multiplier<N-1>::value;
};

template <> struct Multiplier<0>
{
   static const int value = 1;
};

template <int N> RelType compare(double v1, double v2)
{
   return _compare(v1, v2, Multiplier<N>::value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With regards to the correctness of _compare(), it depends what precisely you want to achieve.

In your current implementation:

```
compare<0>(2.499999, 2.500001)
```

returns `RelType::Less`

If this is the answer you want - then fine. However it seems a little odd to say that two numbers which differ by `2e-6`, are not equal at 0 decimal places precision.

Instead try

```
RelType _compare(double v1, double v2, int multiplier)
{
    double margin = vcl_pow(0.1, multiplier);
    if (v1+margin < v2)
        return RelType::Less;
    if (v2+margin < v1
        return RelType::Greater;
    return RelType::Equal;
}
```

Of course, all this can be improved with a little `constexpr` magic, but glampert's answer has that covered.

One other point to note regarding correctness:
C++ bans identifiers in the global namespace beginning with an underscore, giving your current code undefined behaviour according to the standard.

Comment: Interesting points, thank you. There are different use cases for comparing doubles. Often you just want to see if their differences fall within a small margin, as you suggested. Imagine I'm printing `2.499999` and `2.500001` to the console to zero decimal places. This will output 2 and 3, and I would like `compare<0>` to give a result consistent with the printed output. For clarity, I will rename the function to `compareRounded`. Agree with the namespaces comment.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem you have is `using namespace std;`.  It is not a good idea to `using namespace`s in C++ as it can cause problems when multiple functions have the same name.  More can be read about this [at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

It is a good idea to use braces around single-line `if` and loop statements to help ensure the statements go in the correct place:

```
if (std::round(v1 * multiplier) == std::round(v2 * multiplier))
    return RelType::Equal;
if (v1 < v2)
    return RelType::Less;
return RelType::Greater;
```

This appears to be a source of potential errors:

```
template<> RelType compare<5>(double v1, double v2) { return _compare(v1, v2, 100000); }
```

Instead of passing the value needed (100000), you should probably pass the same value as specified in the `<>` section - 5.  Then, you need to change `_compare` to calculate the `multiplier` value with the `pow` function in `cmath`.  This will reduce the number of errors introduced by the programmer mentally calculating or mistyping the value of 10^N needed.

Comment: I want the answer to 10^N at compile time. A requirement is for this function to be efficient and calculating 10^N every time the function is called is needlessly inefficient.

Comment: OK, I see.  However, manually passing the value is an obvious place for errors to occur.

Comment: What would be nice is to have a metafunction that can calculate the `multiplier` from `N`.

Comment: I'm not that advanced at C++, so I'm not really sure what you are talking about.  However, it sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @FrankHippmann See glampert's answer, he has just what you need.